# How do I move onto the next line of code when an application is running?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, printing

I have application Form1 that is being called to run followed by a print command. The code seems to pause once the application is running.

```
[STAThread]
public void Main()
{       
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(new Form1()); 
    Console.WriteLine("Test");  
}
```

In the above scenario, "Test" only gets written after I have closed Form1.

How do I make it so that it writes it while Form1 application is open?
In other words, run the application and continue with the code.

Update: the real logic exists in another method in another class.

```
class otherClass
{
        protected override void realMethod()
        {   

            var myForm = new Program();
            myForm.Main();

           //full logic to run while program is running
}
```

I want the logic in realMethod to run while the program is open. Is that possible?

Comment: I feel this is an XY problem. What exactly do you want to achieve? Can’t you put the code you want to run into the form?

Comment: It looks like, also from you previous post, that you're treating a WinForms app as a Console app. `Console.WriteLine("Test");` will of course be reached only when the application (the Message Loop you just started with `Application.Run()`) terminates. You cannot write to a *Console*, there's no Console, unless you create one. `Console.WriteLine()` writes to the Output Panel in Visual Studio, it's used for debugging purposes.

Comment: Sami I updated to show you how the logic runs.

Comment: @jimi right, this is how I am debugging, and that's how I found out that the code "pauses" when the application is running. I have added some more to this OP for more clarafication.

Comment: You have a *"modal dialog"*. What you are looking for is a *"modeless dialog"*.

Comment: Forms or Console.  Pick **one**.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to determine exactly what you want to achieve, however.

Once your WinForms app starts, it is handing control over to Form1 until it completes its work, then it returns to your writeline statement.  You should make the call to realMethod() from within Form1 or another method that is triggered by Form1.

OR

Load another form instead of Form1 in this line that contains the code you want to execute.

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(new Form1());
```

Comment: The variables defined in realMethod() are constantly changing, but when Form1 is open, the events in realMethod() stop, (pauses) while Form1 is open. How do I have both Form1 open, and realMethod() events happening?

Comment: Without specific information on what your program is doing and more importantly what that method is doing, it is hard to answer.  In general if you want a method to run without impacting the UI (Form1) you need it to run asynchronously, using the async/await pattern. There are many topics on this on SO therefore i suggest you search for these.